# VS2012 SiteMapNode not the same as VS2010?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to upgrade an MVC3 project from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012, however I'm coming across an issue at runtime with the XMLSiteMapProvider code.

I am getting a null reference exception being thrown in VS2012, even though the code happily runs in VS2010, and the code hasn't changed.

My code is as follows:

```
XmlSiteMapProvider site = new XmlSiteMapProvider();
SiteMapNode currentNode = site.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey(HttpContext.Current.Response.ApplyAppPathModifier(HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath));
```

Screenshots of both VS2010 and VS2012 watches are given below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/siajS.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAsMg.png

What you should be able to see is the code above split into its constituent parts to see whats being returned. The important one is the last row in the VS2012 window which chows a null being returned, whilst the "Member Selection" value is found in VS2010.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I have checked the .Net version, and the file versions on the System.Web.dll file which contains this class, and they are the same across both versions of Visual Studio.

The only difference is that VS2012 is running in Win7, whilst VS2010 is running in WinXP.

Could this be IIS version differences?

If I write the following code, VS2012 will correctly work, however VS2010 breaks instead, so it looks as if something is not exactly the same across versions.

```
XmlSiteMapProvider site = new XmlSiteMapProvider();
SiteMapNode currentNode = site.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey(HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath);
```

Any help would be much appreciated,

Nick